# Basic Authentication using RestTemplate in Spring MVC 3.1 status code 301

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, basic-authentication, restful-authentication, resttemplate

I am developing a sample application using Spring MVC 3.1. In this application I am using REST APIs and to use REST APIs I am using Rest Template.

My First page is simple login form, where the user enters a username and password. In the controller, I get these username and password, encode them and send get request for basic authentication.

If the status code is 200 then user is authenticated otherwise it is not.

But I am always getting status code 301.

My Controller code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        String userName = loginForm.getUserName();
        String password = loginForm.getPassword();

        // Basic Authentication

        String token = userName + ":" +password;
        BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(token.getBytes());
        String authHeader = "Basic " + encodedAuthorization;

        System.out.println("authHeader :::::: " + authHeader);

        // Prepare acceptable media type
        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        headers.set("Authorization", authHeader);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri,
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        HttpHeaders header = responseEntity.getHeaders();
        HttpStatus code = responseEntity.getStatusCode();

        System.out.println("Header :::::: " + header);
        System.out.println("Code :::::: " + code);

        // Validation on fields
        validator.validate(loginForm, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }



        // Checkign status is 200 or not

        if ((Integer.parseInt(code.toString())!= 200)) {
            model.addAttribute("formError", "true");
            return "login";
        }
        model.addAttribute(loginForm);
        return "redirect:dateEntry";

    }
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: 301 is a redirection. Did you mean 401?

Comment: When I input any username and password in Login form and process with them then I get these output on console:

authHeader :::::: Basic YWFhYWE6YWFhYQ==

Header :::::: {Server=[nginx/0.7.67], Content-Type=[text/html], Content-Length=[185], Location=[https://www.assembla.com/], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], Date=[Sat, 20 Oct 2012 08:38:14 GMT], Connection=[keep-alive]}

Code :::::: 301

So status code is 301. What is meaning of this and header also not like other requests as Content-Type=[text/html] while  I Set it to applicaiton/xml

Answer (score 0):

A 301 means a permanent redirect. You're probably doing to request to an outdated URL. The Location response header tells you what the new URL is. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301